# setInterval("clock()",50) different from setInterval("clock",50)？

Tags: javascript

Running the code, the browser will display RangeError.

[image]

```
function hide() {
    h -= step;
    pp.style.height = h + "px";
    setTimeout(hide(), 1);
}
```

Comment: MitchWheat and @thefourtheye - I'm sure this is a duplicate of *something*, but not the linked question. The question title is misleading - it doesn't reflect the code shown in the screenshot, which is an infinite recursion problem.

Comment: Don't post images, post text. See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't understand the title and the full code (featuring `h` and `step` vars) is not shown. Consider editing the question. Though my answer might help you.

Comment: The question title only has additional quotes that shouldn't be there to match the code given. Maybe that's the only inconsistency here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
setTimeout(hide(),1);
```

Rather than telling JavaScript to call `hide()` again in 1 millisecond you actually call it immediately and only pass it's return value to `setTimeout()`. This causes an infinite recursion, which in the end causes the stack overflow/error you're getting.

To fix this, you'll have to use either syntax from your question's title:

- Pass the function name only rather than calling it (better here).
- Pass a lambda function.
- Or pass the call inside a string that will be evaluated (IMO should be avoided or replaced with a lambda expression).

However, in your specific scenario I'd suggest using `set Timeout()`, considering your code is reasonably simple to always finish in time:

```
// Start the while thing
var handle = setInterval(hide, 1);

// Actual function
function hide()
{
    // Do stuff

    // End condition
    if (done)
        clearInterval(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't terminate, so it creates infinite number of stacks which causes stack overflow.

Consider adding some termination logic, like:

```
if (h < 0) { return }
```

This terminates the execution of hide() function when `h` is less then 0.

I'm assuming `h` and `step` are some global vars.

Also you're calling `hide` immediately and passing the value to `setTimeout`.

Correct way to recursively call function with timeout will be to pass function as value to `setTimeout` function:

```
setTimeout(hide, 1)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
setTimeout(function() { hide() }, 1)
```

Comment: While this would help in some instances, it wouldn't fix the actual issue: The function is supposed to be called in an interval, but it's actually a recursive call happening immediately.